# python zlib output to c++ string

Tags: c++, python, c, zlib

I am trying to write the output of python zlib's output to a c++ string. The question is very similar to [Python zlib output, how to recover out of mysql utf-8 table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618926/python-zlib-output-how-to-recover-out-of-mysql-utf-8-table) here however, the difference is that my python script generates a C++ header file where the compressed data should be stored as a string. However, because of special characters and raw bytes I am unable to get C++ to read this as a string. The reason I cannot write it to a file and then it back in a c++ program is because this might be a driver component and hence reading files is not allowed. 
Here is a small example of what I am trying.

```
compressed_string = zlib.compress("This is a huge string. Around 263KB")
fptr = open('my_header.h', 'w')

content = "#ifndef __HEADER_DEFS__\n\
#define __HEADER_DEFS__\n\
\n\
#include  \n\
\n\
std::string binary_compressed = \"%s\" \n\
\n\
#endif" % compressed_string

fptr.write(content)
fptr.close()
```

However, the string I am compressing is a huge data, unlike the example I have given here and hence I am adding a screenshot to the kind of characters I am getting in the actual example.

Please take a look at http://tinypic.com/r/1078lxw/7 for the screenshot.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [escape the non-printable characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the string using octal notation.

For example,

```
import string
....
safe_string = ""
for ch in compressed_string:
   if ch in string.printable and ch != '\\':
      safe_string += ch
   else:
      safe_string += "\%o" % ord(ch)
content = ".....\"%s\" ...." % safe_string
```

(It is adviced to avoid hex notation, as that can be variable length and printable characters that follow the escaped character may be legal hexadecimal digits, which will break things)

Comment: Note that `\ ` is still printable yet will induce escaping when parsed by the C/C++ compiler.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to embed binary data into a C++ program, would the Unix [`xxd -i`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd) command help?

That will generate a C header file containing a `char` array representation of a input binary file.

Comment: Even without xxd, generating a char array in python is simple enough.